# Removing properties and inheriting them instead - code first approach

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core-webapi

So, I have been developing a .NET Core Web API application for sports results, teams, competitions, matches... You get the point.

Now, what I did not think of when creating entities is that I will have different types of matches - for each sport a match will have mostly the same properties, but some will be sport specific.
Example: Basketball has 4 quarters, ice hockey has 3 periods, football has only 2 halfs. There are many more examples where match models for these sports differentiate.

The problem is I created initially only one model - Match which has 2 half time properties for each of the 2 teams. 
What I want to do is: remove those 2 properties from the Match model and make the Match a base class which will be inherited by BasketballMatch, FootballMatch, IceHockeyMatch.

Is there a way to restructure this using code first approach without damaging the database? All matches can be deleted if it is needed to delete the table and create a new one with correct inheritance structure.

```
public class Match
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Sport")]
    public int SportID { get; set; }

    public Sport Sport { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Competition")]
    public int CompetitionID { get; set; }

    public Competition Competition { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("HomeTeam")]
    public int HomeTeamID { get; set; }

    public Team HomeTeam { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AwayTeam")]
    public int AwayTeamID { get; set; }

    public Team AwayTeam { get; set; }

    public int? HalfTimeHomeTeamScore { get; set; }

    public int? HalfTimeAwayTeamScore { get; set; }

    public int? HomeTeamScore { get; set; }

    public int? AwayTeamScore { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of how your `Match` entity looks like? Sounds as if you've put both halves into the match itself, thus making the data model pretty much non-extensible.

Comment: @RogerWolf I have added the class now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These:

```
public class Match
{
// ...
    public int? HalfTimeHomeTeamScore { get; set; }

    public int? HalfTimeAwayTeamScore { get; set; }

    public int? HomeTeamScore { get; set; }

    public int? AwayTeamScore { get; set; }
}
```

are separate entities, `MatchPart`s if you like, and they do not belong to the match proper but should rather reference it, due to a number of reasons:

- The amount of match parts per match depends on sport type, and sometimes tournament as well (men's tennis majors play up to 5 sets, everywhere else it's up to 3 sets, for example);
- Some match parts are mandatory, unless the match is cancelled altogether, while others are optional (extra time / penalties in football, tie breaks in tennis). If a particular match has been finished without optional parts, you simply don't have to create records for them;
- There are sub-parts which match parts consist of (again in tennis, sets are comprised of games), so you might need the possibility to organise a hierarchical structure. You might create a separate sub-part table, or put it all together; that's up to you, both approaches are viable if you know SQL well enough;
- You might have multiple score records for the same match part, depending on the score type. In football for example, that would be goals, free / corner kicks, yellow / red cards, penalties, etc. In tennis, additional score types could be aces and double faults, just to name a few.

Please keep in mind that this list is by no means full. I just scratched the surface here, so to speak.

Considering all that, the resulting table might look like the following:

```
create table dbo.MatchParts (
Id bigint identity(1,1) primary key,
MatchId int not null references dbo.Matches (Id),
-- Match part type lookup, big thing in itself
PartTypeId int not null references dbo.MatchPartTypes (Id),
-- Parent part reference for sub-part records, in case you decide to store them all in one table
ParentPartId bigint null references dbo.MatchParts (Id),
-- Position # of part within match or parent
SequenceNumber smallint not null,
-- Score type lookup
ScoreTypeId int not null references dbo.ScoreTypes (Id),
Score1 smallint null,
Score2 smallint null,
-- Natural key. Depends... on many other design decisions.
unique (MatchId, PartTypeId, ParentPartId, ScoreTypeId, SequenceNumber)
);
```

I would strongly suggest to start with an in-depth business analysis of the subject area. It might look simple, but it's not.